# Would this way of proceeding to determine the continuity of a function at a point be correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Is this the proper way to find out whether a function is continuous at a point, using a provided checklist to justify the answer?

[image]

Comment: Well, this is certainly one way to do it. This example is nice, since you don't have to worry about any $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proofs.

Comment: @jasnee So, in exemples like this one, you can avoid checking the continuity on both sides of the limit?

Comment: By "both sides of the limit", do you mean $\lim_{x\nearrow4}$ and $\lim_{x\searrow4}$?

Comment: @jasnee Yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, in this case, the function has the same expression on both sides of the limit point, so you can evaluate the limit in one go

Comment: @Alessandro already answered for me, hope we could help :)

Comment: @jasnee@Alessandro I see. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You could of course observe that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-16}{x-4}&x\ne 4\\8&x=4\end{cases}=\begin{cases}x+4&x\ne 4\\8&x=4\end{cases}=x+4$$, whihc is then obviously continuous ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method to check if $f$ is continuous at any certain point $x_0$ if and only if :
$$(\forall \varepsilon >0) (\exists \delta>0) \ \ \text{st}\ \ \vert x-a\vert<\delta \Rightarrow \big\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\big\vert<\varepsilon $$

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta =\varepsilon $

Suppose that : $\vert x-4\vert<\delta$ and let's show that : $\Big\vert \frac{x^2-16}{x-4} -8\Big\vert<\varepsilon$
We have
\begin{align}
\Bigg\vert \frac{x^2-16}{x-4} -8\Bigg\vert &=\Bigg\vert \frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{x-4}\Bigg\vert\\
&=\vert x-4\vert <\delta
\end{align}
Hence :
$$\Big\vert \frac{x^2-16}{x-4} -8\Big\vert<\delta=\varepsilon$$
Therefore $f$ is continous at $x_0=4$ since :
$$(\forall \varepsilon >0) (\exists \delta>0) \ \ \text{st}\ \ \vert x-4\vert<\delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(4)\vert<\varepsilon $$

---

Generally :
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a} =2a$$
You can prove this using $\varepsilon - \delta$ or using simple algebra.

Your approach is by the way wonderful ,correct, safe and easy.

Good luck.